# coffeescript unexpected INDENT

Tags: coffeescript, sublimetext2

Sometimes when I edit coffeescript files in Sublime text2 I got errors when compile it to js:

```
error: unexpected INDENT
                        $.post url,
```

In sublime text2 editor I see valid indents:

[image: Code print screent]

But if I copy paste this code in plain editor I see wrong indents:

```
click: ->
                            debugger;
                        # delete org here
                        $.post url,
```

`debugger;` string has wrong extra indent.

So how to edit coffeescript files in sublime text 2 with pleasure?
I got installed [coffeescript](https://github.com/Xavura/CoffeeScript-Sublime-Plugin) package in sublime.

My `Preferences.sublime-settings` file is the following:

```
{
    "auto_indent": true,
    "auto_match_enabled": true,
    "detect_indentation": true,
    "draw_centered": false,
    "font_size": 11.0,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Better CoffeeScript",
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "indent_guide_options":
    [
        "draw_active"
    ],
    "indent_subsequent_lines": true,
    "indent_to_bracket": true,
    "smart_indent": true,
    "tab_size": 2,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "trim_automatic_white_space": true,
    "use_tab_stops": true,
    "word_wrap": "auto",
    "wrap_width": 0
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing tabs and spaces. Select `View->Indentation` and make sure that `Indent Using Spaces` is checked, then click `Convert Indentation to Spaces` and you should be all set.